# UIDatePicker, choosing date shows one day earlier

Tags: swift

I have a UIDatePicker, getting the date from the picker shows different date (one day earlier) from what I chose.

```
For example, choosing May 2, 2019, shows 2019-05-01
```

This is where I get the date for my variable:

```
    @objc func datePickerValueChanged(sender: UIDatePicker){
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
    dateTextField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)

    //Tag 9 is the startDateTextField, Tag 8 is the EndDateTextField
    //We need this to know which variable should get the date choosen.
    if dateTextField.tag == 9 {
        startDateChoosen = sender.date
    }else if dateTextField.tag == 8 {
        endDateChoosen = sender.date
    }
}
```

This is what I see on the screen:
[image]

Comment: your picture shows May 2. Btw not related to your question but your code will create a new DateFormatter every time the picker changes. You should declare your DateFormatter as a property of your controller or make it a static property of Formatter

Comment: Where are you seeing `2019-05-01`?

Comment: @rmaddy he is probably printing it

Comment: @rmaddy printing the variable where I store the date.

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks, may 2 is what should be and it is shown to the user, the problem is with the variable where I store the date, printing this variable gives a day earlier. And yes, the dateformatter should not be there I will fix it, thanks!

Comment: @JohnDoah This has been discussed many times. When you print a Date value, it is shown in UTC time. It's fine. There's nothing wrong.

Answer (score -1):

The issue might be with the time zone that is set on your iPad/iPhone that you are using. Make sure the time zone set in the settings is of that of your current location.